# What is the technique that should be used to evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\sin (k\sin \theta))^2 \,d\theta\ $?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

> $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\sin (k\sin \theta))^2 \,d\theta\ $$ Where $k$ is a real constant.

I searched for it and found out that it 'does not have an integral 
I tried using a substitution for sinθ but then both limits change to zero

expressible with elementary functions'. What does this mean? If so how to solve it?

Comment: I tried using a substitution for $sin\theta$ but then both limits change to zero.

Comment: Include your work in the question not in comments

Comment: Your substitution must be bijective on the bounds of the integral for it to be valid

Comment: have you tried to use the identity $(\sin t)^2=1/2(1-\sin t)$ on the following webpage are some other that could help you to better undertand the problem http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function

Comment: Even if i use $(\sin t)^2=1/2(1-\sin t)$ then the term $\sin (k\sin \theta)$ will come into the expression which would be again a problem when integrating.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\sin (k\sin \theta))^2 \,d\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac12\left(1-\cos (2k\sin \theta)\right) \,d\theta$$
where
$$\int_0^{\pi} \cos(x\sin t)\ dt=\pi J_0(x)$$
and $J_0$ is Bessel function of order $0$.